# Form Submit + PHP Server Variables Changes Page Absolute Urls - htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])

Tags: php, url, absolute-path, document-root

I have a PHP config file which defined server environment vars to be use throughout the site. I'm a little perplex on why my config settings aren't working after a form submission using "htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])".

The form validate + sanitize inputs and then updates the database perfectly. However after submission all of the page absolute paths switches to document root paths. This error creates incorrect links for the css + js. All the links are correct on page load - they just change after post submit.  I've even tried multiple reserved server variables listed on http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php to no success.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for any wisdom shared. ;-)

ENV vars:

```
<?php
  $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  $stage = 'domain.net';
  $prod = 'domain.com';
  $dev = 'localhost';

  if ($url == $dev){
    $path = 'http://'.$url. dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    include_once 'dev.php';
  } elseif ($url == $stage) {
    $path = 'http://'.$url. dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    include_once 'stage.php';
  } else {
    $path = 'http://'.$url;
    include_once 'prod.php';
  }
?>
```

Form Markup Before:

```
<form id="idname" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($path . '/' . basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));?>" method="post">
```

Form Markup After:

```
<form id="idname" action="/Users/username/Sites/project/folder" method="post">
```

Stylesheet Link Before:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, handheld" href="/Users/username/Sites/project/folder/css/global.css">
```

Stylesheet Link After:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, handheld" href="/Users/username/Sites/project/folder/css/global.css">
```

Fixed the bug. End up revising my code.

```
$url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$dir = dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$env = array(
    'dev' => 'http://localhost/'. $dir, 
    'stage' => 'http://domain.net/'. $dir, 
    'prod' => 'http://domain.com' 
);

if ($url !== $env['prod']) {
    if($url === $env['stage']) {
        $env = $env['stage'];
        include_once 'stage.php';
    } else {
        $env = $env['dev'];
        include_once 'dev.php';
    }
} else {
    $env = $env['prod'];
    include_once 'prod.php';
}
```

Comment: Is there any additional information needed on my part in order to expedite the process? I'm just at a lost at what could have went wrong. Thanks.

Comment: This has been resolved. The culpit... a duplicate variable calling a different path for a script in another function.  Up too late coding I guess.